# Unable to store cookies in war deployed from Tomcat7

Tags: java, grails, tomcat7

I am using/trying to deploy grails war app to the tomcat7 virtual host configured in server.xml. I have modified etc/hosts to redirect www.mytest.com to localhost (referred from ramkitech). There seems no problem in the code as it works in development(By this, I mean I run my code from `grails run-app` and access http://localhost:8080/app/). The problem is when I deploy it to independent tomcat7 and put it as ROOT.war in the webapps folder and run the tomcat service, I can access the war based app at http://www.mytest.com:8080/ and when I try to set cookies, they do not seem to be stored and hence, I can't access the cookies set. By the way, the war was generated by the `grails dev war`. What could be going wrong here?

Server.xml

```
<Host name="www.mytest.com" appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" >
   <Alias>mytest.com</Alias>
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

I referred this from http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/02/understanding-virtual-host-concept-in.html and I am using grails [cookie plugin 1.4](https://grails.org/plugin/cookie) and basically call `savePreference()` with ajax providing sample cookie from the the view.

```
def savePreference(Map cleanParams=[:]) {
  cleanParams.each{key,val->
      cookieService.setCookie(key, val)
  }
  return "OK"
}
```

and here is sample cookie key value pairs I store:

```
prod_type:A
prod_categoryId:2
prod_id:3
```

Comment: Creating the war in development mode isn't going to disable your ability to store cookies. Can you provide your code that you're using for storing cookies?

Comment: And you've checked the HTTP response?

Comment: The cookie key value pairs are in the response header with "Set-Cookie" of the ajax I call i.e in the savePreference ajax but when I reload the main page, there is no Cookie mentioned in the request header.

Comment: And are you setting an expiry time for these cookies or are they session cookies?

Comment: Yeah, the expiry time is one day.
Set-Cookie:prod_type=A; Version=1; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Mon, 03-Aug-2015 01:27:03 GMT; Path=""; HttpOnly

Comment: Can I see the code for that?

Comment: I use grails cookie plugin for setting the cookie. Here's my default config at Config.groovy (grails.plugins.cookie.cookieage.default = 86400), rest of setting takes place in the cookieService.